# React - Filter JSON array if key exists

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How do I check and filter id a particular key exists in a JSON array?

This is my json array

```
[
 {
   "key": 1
 },
 {
   "key": 2
 },
 {
   "Gene": "JAK1",
   "key": 3
 },
 {
   "Gene": "ALK",
   "key": 4
 },
 {
   "key": 5
 }
]
```

I just want to make an another array if the key "Gene" exists. like this.,

```
[
 {
   "Gene": "JAK1",
   "key": 3
 },
 {
   "Gene": "ALK",
   "key": 4
 }
]
```

Comment: use filter `arr.filter(obj => 'Gene' in obj)`

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: `arr.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('Gene'))`